# plt.bar in python generates empty plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data set as follows

| province_territory | turbines |
| --- | --- |
| Yukon | 2 |
| Northwest territories | 4 |
| Prince Edward Island | 27 |
| New Brunswick | 104 |

The data is already sorted in ascending order and I want to make a bar plot.

```
plt.bar('turbines','province_territory',data=turbinesperprovince_sorted)
```

I have tried the syntax above and it generates a blank plot. I have tried assigning X and Y to each variable and I end up with a solid block as a plot. I am learning python and completely stuck on this. Please help. What is the correct syntax? What libraries should I use, right now I have imported matplotlib, also tried seaborn. Nothing works.

Edited to add: this is how the plot appears when I plot it.
[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiuXD.png)
I have tried the suggestions below once again, I still get the same result

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're using the correct dataframe as `data`? It worked fine for me (though `plt.bar('province_territory','turbines', data=turbinesperprovince_sorted)` gave a much clearer result than switching x and y the other way around. )

Comment: It seems like `turbinesperprovince_sorted['turbines']` could be stored as strings. You can do: `turbinesperprovince_sorted['turbines'] = turbinesperprovince_sorted['turbines'].astype(int)` to address that.